# Difference between similarly parenthesized function types

Tags: function, haskell, types, currying

I'm really stuck with functions types in Haskell. There are the types of two functions given and I cannot explain what's the real difference between those.

```hs
a :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Int)))

b :: (((Int -> Int) -> Int) -> Int) -> Int
```

I still don't get the point. I know what the purpose of currying is -- but I cannot see the concept of currying in this example!

function a: an `Int` is passed in, and the result is another that takes an `Int` ... and so on.

function b: How is this different from function A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the best thing to do is to think about two simpler functions:

```
f :: a -> (b -> c)
g :: (a -> b) -> c
```

Let's look at these functions in turn.

The first function, `f`, takes a single parameter of type `a`, and returns a function of type `b -> c`. In other words, you could write something like the following, assuming `x :: a`, `y :: b`, and `z :: c`:

```
f :: a -> (b -> c)
f x = f'
  where f' :: b -> C
        f' y = z
```

Another way to write the signature of `f` is as:

```
f :: a -> b -> c
```

This works because by default we bind `->` to the right. It also gives us another equivalent way of understanding `f`: it can be thought of a function that takes two parameters, of type `a` and `b`, and produces a result of type `c`.

The second function, `g` takes one argument, which is a function of type `a -> b`.

```
g :: (a -> b) -> c
g h = z
  where h :: a -> b
```

Thus the two are very different.

Applying this to your functions, the first function takes 4 values of type `Int` and returns an `Int`. The second function takes a single function of type `((Int -> Int) -> Int) -> Int`, and that's a function that takes a third function of type `(Int -> Int)` and produces an `Int`, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Function `b` takes a function as its argument - it does not produce a function as its result. That is a big difference:

`a 42` will produce a function that takes additional arguments. `b 42` will produce a type error because `42` is not a function. `b myfun` where `myfun` has type `((Int -> Int) -> Int) -> Int)` will produce an `Int`. `a myfun` will cause a type error because `myfun` is not an integer.